# Maximum distance of a body in projectile motion from origin

Tags: classical-mechanics, projectile

Suppose a body is in projectile motion then what will be the maximum distance it can attain from origin?

Also in what case the range will be the maximum distance from the origin compared to other points in the path?

Comment: Duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94436/207455

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about the range equation, but I don't understand the wording of the second question.

Comment: I m asking in what condition the range of the projectile will be that maximum distance?